# Failed to resolve android.design.26.0.0 and appcompat

Tags: android

[image: Click to view image]

**BuildGrade in /src**

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.amirqadir.finalchat"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //compile 'com.android.support:design:26'
    //firebase dependencies
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database  '
    compile 'com.google.android:design:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
}
```

**Build Gradle of whole project**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have tried everything none works I have tried installing repository etc.Its been 2 days I am stuck here
Is there anyway, I can surpass this as you can see in the above code I have used same version at every step but it still gives me error

I have seen somewhere they asked to add a dependency of google in build.gradle Which I already did as you can see

Answer (score 0):

The latest support library version is `26.1.0` so make sure you change to this from `26.0.0`.

Upgrade your gradle version for sdk 26. Make sure the dependencies in your top level `build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
}
```

Also, the repositories should look like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Check your `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file. It should have this line:
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip`

Lastly, you can remove the attribute `buildToolsVersion` in `app`'s `build.gradle` file as it is not required when you have the latest gradle version.

Comment: error  could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1

Comment: Check the distribution url first to see if the version in it is 4.1

Comment: No it's distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip

Comment: Change that to 4.1 and do the rest. Sync when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

add the following at the end of the Module app build

```
     apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and also update the google services and firebase plugins versions..

```
     classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
      classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the dependency

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'

into

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'

Comment: It was earlier 26.+ (issue remain same)

Comment: To use support libraries starting from version 26.0.0 you need to add Google's Maven repository to your project's build.gradle file as described here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html

Comment: allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
        }
    }

Comment: if you are using android 3.0 or above you have to change Maven Repository to maven{ google()  }

Comment: I have already done that If you could please check the above code
or do I need to need to place it on my /src  build.gradle file 


Basically, I am confused between two gradle

Comment: See There is two Gradle Files One for Project Module and second is For Build.Gradle<App> Put this repository into Build.Gradle<Module>